# Delete All Cart Items Endpoint returns woocommerce_rest_cart_error in store api

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'am calling the delete all cart items endpoint with the X-WC-Store-API-Nonce. But I'am getting back woocommerce_rest_cart_error error. I have tried the add-item and remove-items endpoints. Both are working fine when triggered with nonce. But the delete endpoint is failing. I have checked in code and found the get_cart_instance() function is returning null for wc-cart() for this delete request.
**DELETE /cart/items/**
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

**1.Trigger curl --request DELETE https://example-store.com/wp-json/wc/store/cart/items with X-WC-Store-API-Nonce and JWT token
2.API response is {"code":"woocommerce_rest_cart_error","message":"Unable to retrieve cart.","data":{"status":500}}**

I have installed **JWT Auth – WordPress JSON Web Token Authentication By Author: Useful Team**.
So iam passing the jwt token for in authorization header also.

Can someone suggest a solution for this.?

Answer (score 0):

Friend, the endpoint routes ["/wc/store/cart/remove-item"] didn't work for me either, I didn't know how to make it work at the first opportunity.

And this routes ["/wc/store/cart/items"] only returns the items that I have in the cart and although it allows Post, Get and Update, I didn't know how to make it work either.

However ... I share the following with you and whoever can help this for the rest of woocommerce api.

I was successful in removing items with the same routes endpoint ["/wc/store/cart/add-item"] by placing a negative number (-1) in the value of the quantity argument.

and to eliminate all the products of the same items, recover the existing quantity (using the GET of /wc/store/cart/items) and make it negative. (-route.quantity).

I share an image of the functions achieved with this way.

[Functions achieved to remove items one by one or all added units of the same item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2G1z.png)

In this way I can eliminate items one by one and all in case an item has several units added to the cart.

Now, in case you want to delete all the items in a single action, what happens to me is to execute a cycle for each existing items in the cart, eliminating all their units and even though there are several requests to the endpoint for now, it is the option that I see for to achieve this..

Waiting for a more effective documented way with a single call to the endpoint for all the items in the cart and their quantities, I think this for loop could work.

Share the example with negative number

```
fetch("https://yourxdomainx.com/wp-json/wc/store/cart/add-item", {
          "method": "POST",
          "headers": {
            "X-WC-Store-API-Nonce": 'NONCEHERE'// woononce,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          "body": `{\"id\":\"${id_item}\",\"quantity\":\"-${negativenumber}\"}`  
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
          console.log('err');
        });
```

If you execute this fetch for each item in your cart and placing their quantities on it, you will eliminate them all.

I repeat ...

Fetch responses will arrive at different times for fractions of seconds and not in a single call or response. However, they will all be eliminated.

Note for the beginning:
Running this url in simple fetch in your proyect to read all existing routes. This helps a lot.
https://yourxdomainx.com/wp-json/wc/store

[Routes Help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe5Vw.png)